# Handling Local File of Image URLs AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the project I'm working on, I have a text file of image URLs that should be included in the page I'm working on (the images themselves, that is). From research online, all I have found is making an $http request over the file:// protocol. Are there any better ways of accessing these URLs through the main controller? I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I could not find any satisfactory answers out there.

Comment: What do you mean by "better ways"?

Comment: As in, is that the "proper" way to go about file reads in angular?

Comment: Is the project offline, using `file:` protocol? Not certain `angular` or, how else the file could be retrieved, besides, perhaps using `input type="file"` element. What is issue with using making  request at `file:` protocol?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you should run a server and serve the file containing urls on server, so that angular can make a http call to get the file contents and hence the urls.